# Gasses and Gravity

Tags: gravity, atoms, ideal-gas

I have two questions.

First question.
When gas is placed inside a container it fills the container evenly with constant pressure. If the container size varies the gas expands or is compressed but the particles are still evenly distributed. My question is at what scale does this break down and a pressure gradient is formed. If you had a closed container a mile high that was attached to the ground the gas inside would experience varying amounts of gravity. There has to be some point that even in a closed container the pressure cant be constant.

Second question.
If a gas in compressed inside a container would the gas ever settle. The atoms are colliding  with the insides of the container and releasing some energy as a result. Would this lead to cooling over time.

Comment: There is ALWAYS a pressure gradient in any container of non-zero height in a gravity field. It may be very small but it's always there.  Bonus question: why does a helium balloon in a car move backwards when the car decelerates instead of forwards (in the car's reference frame)?

Comment: Has to do with buoyancy and and pressure around the balloon. If accelerating the pressure is less in front of the balloon and greater behind it. The balloon moves forward because it is less dense than the air behind it.

Comment: yes, I was posing that as a thought experiment for the OP. On deceleration the air moves to the front slightly creating a front-to-back pressure gradient.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you have a closed container or just look at the open atmosphere, the pressure and density fall with altitude.  If you consider a small volume of air, it has a small weight.  To keep it from falling, you need a higher pressure at the bottom than at the top which compensates for the weight.  You can use this to compute the pressure decrease in an isothermal atmosphere. The pressure falls about 2 psi from sea level to 4000 feet, for example.

Though the atoms in the container are colliding, the collisions are elastic, so no energy is absorbed.  As long as there is no heat flow through the walls, the temperature will stay constant.